# What do the passport stamps for Guernsey and Jersey look like?

Tags: passport-stamps, channel-islands

I am curious as to what the passport entry stamp for the Bailiwick of Guernsey and Bailiwick of Jersey look like. I would assume that I would receive a stamp if I enter from France since I am leaving Schengen and entering CTA. I've tried searching but surprisingly can't find anything.

Comment: It's extraordinarily rare for anyone to post pictures of any particular passport stamp online, compared to the total number of travellers to that port of entry. So you can find lots of Heathrow stamps, the occasional Paris, Manchester, Birmingham or Edinburgh stamp, but other stamps are very hard to find, or impossible. It's even possible that no one has considered them noteworthy enough to take a picture of and post online.

Comment: Are you travelling there or making plans? If yes, it would be nice if you could share whether you could get such a stamp!

Comment: [This Home Office document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area) mentions the stamps, but the photos have been redacted. Very frustrating, and quite silly. What's the point in redacting stamps you put in people's passports?

Comment: I added your link to my answer, thanks for thinking to look it up! It could have been a good source were the images not redacted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is the entry stamp of Alderney (Bailiwick of Guernsey) - a UK stamp but with crowns rather than stars to designate officer ranks.

Passports of EU/EFTA states, Australia, Canada, Japan, New Zealand, Singapore, South Korea and the US are **not** stamped; however, the officer had no problem giving me the stamp (which is on a blank sheet).

[image]

Comment: do you have an answer to this part of the original question?

"I would assume that I would receive a stamp if I enter from France since I am leaving Schengen and entering CTA."

I'm not sure if it is possible for CTA or Schengen residents / EU citizens to get a stamp in their passport when they normally would be exempt.

Comment: @JakeDot We know nothing of OP's citizenship. Residence means nothing, only the passport used (except when an Article 10/20 card is used alongside the passport). FWIW, I'm an EU citizen but the officer had no problem giving me the stamp (on a blank sheet), though I had to wait for the others to pass (almost all French ID card holders so it was quick)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to scan/upload a picture!

Comment: @Crazydre do you know if this has changed after Brexit, do they stamp EU passports now? I'll go to Alderney from France next month. Passports are now required, ID cards no longer sufficient.

Comment: @JakeDot No, EU/Schengen, Australian, Canadian, Japanese, New Zealand, Singaporean, South Korean and US passports aren't stamped. Besides, specific categories of EU/Schengen citizens can still enter on an ID card (people below 19 in a school group, plus all categories that can enter the UK on one

Answer (score 4):

You will not necessarily receive a stamp. I have travelled from Schengen to CTA (both UK and Ireland, and also from the UK on to Isle of Man, Jersey and Guernsey) multiple times and have never received a stamp.

It may depend on your citizenship.

I think you can ask on arrival if they can stamp your passport. I heard from some travellers that they like to collect the stamps and usually are able to get their passports stamped on request.

---

I just found a better answer to your question:

> In addition, Guernsey, Jersey and the Isle of Man apply UK entry regulations and issue UK entry stamps in passports. Consequently, the UK is henceforth taken to include these territories.

So, the stamps would presumably look like UK stamps, with text referring to the respective location.

An Example can be seen below in [the answer of Crazydre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138958/95392) - it shows that the stars in normal UK stamps are replaced by crowns.

Source: [Answer to "uk - What do non-EU/Schengen citizens need [...] when travelling [...] CTA?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138746/95392)

---

As MJeffryes mentions in a comment above:

> [This Home Office document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area) mentions the stamps, but the photos have been redacted.

Comment: If you are an EU/EEA citizen (which looks probable since your profile says you're in Austria), then you won't get any stamps from Ireland or the UK. It's different for people who are not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  Do we know whether that will change when/if Brexit happens?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: It definitely won't change for Ireland; what happens for the UK nobody knows at this point.

Comment: Uploaded an image