# Travelling out from Dublin airport to UAE

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, international-travel

I have a UK visit visa, I arrived last July at a UK airport.
Now I would like to change my flight back to Asia next month by using Dublin airport on my way out. Do I need an Irish visa to use Dublin airport by going out?

UK/Ireland has agreement that those with UK visit short visa can travel through Ireland but its not clear for me about using airport for going out for travel to other country.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer the question. Please edit your post (using the "edit" button below the tags) to show your proposed itinerary as well as your citizenship — many visa/transit issues have different answers depending on the country passport and travel document being carried by the traveler.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

Answer (score 1):

Both the United Kingdom and the Republic of Ireland have a common Immigration policy called the [Common Travel Area](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area).
This [Answer goes into further details](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138746/95267).

Although both countries may have different policies for Foreigners, in most cases where a British Visa or **leave to enter** exists, no Irish visa is needed and vice versa.

Leaving Ireland with a valid British **leave to enter** should cause no problem.

Check the Wikipedia article if your country is listed.