# Visiting UK and Ireland with a single visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I have to travel to both Dublin, Ireland and London, UK on short 2 day duration trips. Since both require visa for my country to enter, I started the Irish visa process and paid the fees. I later realized that they have something called as Common Travel Area thing where you can travel to both on a single visa from one. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme#visiting-the-uk-and-ireland

Now I am confused on what to do. If I end up applying for both the visas one after the other, the turnaround time means that it will take about 6 weeks for me to get both the visas. The Irish visa thing in the policy mentioned above covers four short term visas but doesn't cover the one I applied for which is `Short Stay-Other`. My option seems to be to apply for the UK visa and then use that to travel to Ireland and just forget about the loss on fees for the Irish visa. Does this make sense?

Also, if I am not understanding the CTA policy correctly, do clarify on that as well. Thanks.

Comment: What's your nationality? The page you linked says that currently the scheme applies only to Indian and Chinese nationals.

Comment: While the CTA exists, there isn't really much in the way of common visa policy - ther eis the very limited scheme you mention, but it is very limited.

Comment: @Muzer I am from India so it does apply to me as well.

Comment: @CMaster The UK visa I needed to travel to UK seems to be the one mentioned on the link above.

Comment: Which country are you visiting first? If you apply for a BIV you have to enter through the country that issued your visa (section  5 https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme). There’s a good overview of how the CTA works here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

Comment: @Traveller Actually the plan wasn't fixed till now. But whichever visa I take, I will visit that country first as pointed out in the link you gave. Thanks for the second link, I will go through that.

Comment: btw, @Traveller since you are from UK. Do you know if Brexit will change any of this? I haven't found anything regarding this being stopped.

Comment: @erosenin No, I don’t - but it’s a good question, you should post it separately.

Comment: @Traveller Will do, I will just search for it a bit first.