# Do I need a visa for Dublin

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, common-travel-area

I am travelling from Mauritius to UK for a few days then to Dublin for 3 days. Do I require a visa for Dublin

Comment: Are you traveling on a Mauritius passport?

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Mauritian citizen, then yes you do need a visa to visit Ireland. From [Visa policy of Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Ireland):

> Visa policy of Ireland is similar to the visa policy of the Schengen Area. It grants visa-free entry to all Schengen Annex II nationalities, **except for** Albania, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Colombia, Georgia, Marshall Islands, **Mauritius**, Micronesia, Moldova, Montenegro, North Macedonia, Palau, Peru, Serbia, Timor-Leste, Ukraine and Venezuela.