# US citizen to UK for tourism - but also working remotely for US company - _new for 2023_

Tags: uk, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, work

There are already a couple of questions here about whether a US citizen can go to the UK for say 3 months (within the visa-free limit) for tourism but *also* while there work remotely for his US employer.  (E.g., [here is one I asked 3 years ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154972/us-citizen-to-uk-or-eu-for-vacation-but-working-remotely-from-time-to-time-for).)

But looking again, in 2023, I see *now* the official [UK site](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism) says:

> While in the UK as a tourist, you cannot:
>
> - do paid or unpaid work for a UK company or as a self-employed person

(That was for the US visa-free entry, there's also [here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor) for standard visa.)

But that seems *different wording* IIRC my previous visits there.  Now it is expressly qualified with "UK company".  (And I'm assuming that "or as a self-employed person" also refers to working for UK clients as a self-employed person.  But that isn't relevant to this question anyway as I am employed by a US company.)

So have the rules changed?  Can I *now* travel in/live in/commit tourism in the UK while doing remote work for the US company where I'm a full-time employee?

Comment: The rules have always been the same. Many people want to interpret it as very strict but its never been. What the law means is that you cannot work for a UK company. And that's it. You can work abroad on vacation for a US based employer, no problem.

Comment: @AussieJoe This isn't correct. In "Remote Work" within the [official UK Guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1112745/Visit_caseworker_guidance_12.pdf#page31) this text appears: "Visitors are permitted to undertake activities relating to their employment overseas remotely whilst they are in the UK, such as responding to emails or answering phone calls. However, you should check that the applicant’s main purpose for coming to the UK is to undertake a permitted activity, rather than specifically to work remotely from the UK."

Comment: Don't really understand why this question was closed as a dup since it is clear from the question that the main entry page for UK visas has _changed_ w.r.t. how it describes permitted work and apparently that doesn't match the still existent rules.

Comment: @davidbak because the same people make the same poor choices on these answers.

Comment: @davidbak The entry page for UK visas is a summary/overview, not the complete story. The Rules regarding permitted activities for visitors are here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities

Comment: @AussieJoe A visitor to the UK can only work there for a non UK-based company *if* the type of work being performed is listed here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities Remote working as a tourist in the UK is not explicitly mentioned as a permitted activity, therefore it is not allowed

Comment: Your assumption regarding self-employed is wrong. You cannot work in the UK as a visitor while self employed for *any* clients is how that phrase should be interpreted - there's no link with the "UK company" in the first part of the phrase. I think in practicse if you were say, a contractor to a US company here for a few weeks it would be fine, but they're seeking to not say, have software developers living here for 6 months while remaining untaxed etc.

Comment: @CMaster - I get what you're saying - there's a separate clause saying how you can't use the "visa less" entry to essentially stay in the UK over a long time (with brief interruptions).

Comment: @AussieJoe do you imagine that a US citizen who tells an immigration officer "I'm planning to spend every weekday afternoon and evening from 2 to 10 and evening writing code for my employer in the US; otherwise I'll be visiting historic sites in London" will be admitted?  Everything I've seen indicates the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the page was updated after Nov. 2020 with the new structure (https://web.archive.org/web/20201112034638/https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism)

Looking through the changes to the rules in that period (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/updates) it seems to have been an effect of the new point-based system implemented for Brexit.

Comment: The UK’s points-based immigration system is not relevant to visitor visas

Comment: @Traveller but a broader reassessment of immigration policy could well have been undertaken at the same time.