# Problem with UK immigration when leaving via land border with Ireland?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, borders, ireland, northern-ireland

I am flying from USA to London England, then to Belfast Northern Ireland. My flight back to USA departs from Dublin, so to catch my flight I will cross the land border between Northern Ireland (UK) and Republic of Ireland, which is uncontrolled.

Like USA, I assume UK has records of people leaving via plane to track overstays, even if there is no physical exit control. Will my itinerary cause a problem with UK immigration because they have no record of how I left the country?

(my citizenship is USA)

Comment: [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr) suggests you'll need to get an Irish entry stamp when you cross the NI border. Presumably they'll let the UK know that you've left

Comment: Ireland and the UK share immigration data, so UK will know when you've left the CTA.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it should be an issue when you leave. The common travel area allows both Ireland and the UK to share information whenever people enter and leave the area.