# Traveling with temporary residence work permit

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, cypriot-citizens

Hello everyone my question is i have a child that has cypriot passport and as the family of an eu citizen i was given a resident work permit card and i will like to know if i can travel to uk or ireland without applying for visa with my child and also be able to work there Thanks

Comment: This https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa will tell you whether you need a visa for the UK. The UK and Ireland are part of the Common Travel Area https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

Comment: Is your child a minor?

Answer (score 1):

UK is no longer a member of EU, so get that out of the equation here. To travel to Ireland, you need to apply for a visa as that is based on your citizenship. Neither Ireland, nor Cyprus are Schengen members so they have border control. Once you are in Ireland, you can apply for an EEA permit based on "derivative rights" as long as you can prove the child is "self-sifficient" economically and has health insurance. Then you can work in Ireland. How that pracitally works in the case of a minor child, I am not sure. You can get more information here at the official Irish immigration website:

https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/rights_of_residence_in_ireland/residence_rights_eu_national.html

Comment: Under the directive, parents are not eligible for derivative rights unless the _parent_ is dependent on the _child._  There may be some court case that establishes a derivative right that isn't explicit in the directive; I haven't kept up with those developments.

Comment: Yes, that's why I provided the link in the answer. That link is specific to Ireland and mentions that parents of minor children can apply based on a certain court case.