# When arriving in Dublin by train from Belfast, Passport Stamp at Burgh Quay?

Tags: uk, international-travel, ireland, northern-ireland

I will be taking train from Belfast to Dublin in next few days and am required to report my entry to immigration officer at Burgh Quay according to their website (I’m non-EU/UK and hold Irish visit visa and UK resident permit).

I notice the Burgh Quay Office now adopts an appointment-based system, just not sure if tourists like me could just walk in to report an entry or have to follow the appointment route (it is very hard to book appointment for this because: 1) I will only stay in Dublin for several days and 2) they just don’t answer my phone and emails, there’s no way I can book an appointment with them beforehand).

I have tried to call Burgh Quay for two days and simply no one answered the phone. I previously sent them an email to ask about it and still haven’t heard back after three days.

Just wonder is there anyone experiencing the same? Wonder how do you report your entry to Burgh Quay? It is so hard because I just can’t hear anything from Burgh Quay Registration Office.

As I will be flying back to London via Dublin Airport, I don’t want to get into trouble due to the lack of Ireland entry stamp.

Comment: "I don’t want to get into trouble due to the lack of Ireland entry stamp." There is no exit immigration check in Ireland; in any case, there is no routine immigration control inside the Common Travel Area. In the most probable case, no one will care.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

Answer (score 9):

[This Irish Government webpage](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/entry-for-non-eu-non-eea-and-non-swiss-nationals/) says:

> **What to do if you arrive via the border with Northern Ireland**
>
> If you arrive via the border with Northern Ireland, you must report to an Immigration Officer at Burgh Quay, Registration Office, Dublin or your local Immigration Office at a Garda Síochána (Irish Police) station as soon as possible.

Thus: go to the Burgh Quay Registration Office when you arrive in Dublin.

If the Burgh Quay office is closed or otherwise unavailable — a web search (see [this Irish government page](https://www.gov.ie/en/press-release/61092-burgh-quay-registration-office-reopening-10-may-2021/) and [this secondary source](https://berkeleysolicitors.ie/reopening-of-burgh-quay-registration-office/)) suggests that the office is open only by appointment — then find a Garda office and go there. The Irish government has an [online Garda office finder](https://www.garda.ie/en/contact-us/station-directory/).

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your info. I have used that service and asked several Dublin Garda station and they say I have to attend the Burgh Quay Office because they take full charge of the Greater Dublin Area. It’s just that Burgh Quay doesn’t answer my phone and emails… I don’t know what to do next..

Comment: It is unfortunately common that some government offices don't respond to phone and email; this behavior is not limited to Ireland. You cannot compel an office to pay attention to you. All you can do is go to the physical location and try. If they won't see you, try another Garda location and report that Burgh Quay won't talk to you.

Comment: Thanks! Just a update! I have finally managed to get Burgh Quay pick up my phone call, they say they only handle long-stay permissions and my short-term tourist visa is not in their scope. They ask me to ask Garda Station even though I keep telling them their website says I should go to them. I then called back several Garda Station again and they said the same thing that I should go to Burgh Quay…. Anyway, I will update my post after my trip to Dublin.. Hope I can get everything sorted successfully.

Answer (score 7):

The statement on the website is inaccurate.

There's no point going to Burgh Quay. The earliest appointment you would get would probably be a few weeks away. And as the questioner says Burgh Quay only handle long-stays.

The actual position is set out in [section 4(5) of the Immigration Act 2004](http://revisedacts.lawreform.ie/eli/2004/act/1/revised/en/html#SEC4), which provides that non-nationals entering the Republic of Ireland by land can remain in the state for up to a month without getting a permission to land, provided they:

- have a visa if they require one and,
- are not looking to "engage in employment, business or a profession".

As far as I know the only place for tourists to get an entry stamp is at an airport.

On the plus side:

- There are no exit controls in Ireland so there will be no one to
  query your lack of an entry stamp when leaving Dublin.
- Arrivals in UK airports from Ireland are not subject to any controls
  either.

Comment: "As far as I know the only place for tourists to get an entry stamp is at an airport." No, seaports too. When I went by bus London-Cork, three Americans were stamped in at Rosslare. Interesting that one can only stay for 1 month. How does one solve it if wanting to stay 1-3 months?

Comment: More importantly, absolute disaster that an official government website can be so wrong. Didn't know Ireland was a third-world sh*thole in that regard.