Why do Irish authorities check passports of those entering Britain?
I am a British citizen and took a flight from Toronto to Dublin and then Dublin to Manchester, both with Aer Lingus.
I was surprised that I had my passport checked in Dublin by the Irish authorities and then not checked in Manchester.
I would have thought that the  Irish authorities would not have checked passengers entering Britain with the same level of concern as the British  authorities.

There is a very long established legal relationship between the UK and the Republic of Ireland called the “Common Travel Area” which provides for internal travel between the 2 countries without a requirement for a passport for Irish and UK citizens. There’s a bit more to it than that but the underlying principle is that each country protects the other’s borders, and that allows each others citizens to travel to and live in the other jurisdiction without any immigration controls. So no formal passport control between Dublin and the UK.

(+1) Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

It’s also worth noting that nearly all connecting passengers will undergo passport control when connecting in Dublin.

In fact, in the reverse direction, passport control is performed by Ireland. The UK unilaterally chooses not to routinely perform it from Ireland.

@jcaron What's the exception? AFAIK there's none, with even domestic arrivals clearing immigration

@Crazydre you supposedly can do airside connections without going through passport control if both your arriving and departing flights are at T2 and within specific hours. All other arrivals do indeed go through passport control.

@jcaron Nope, that involves a "transfer immigration" check, which is available at T2 only, so it does provide a visa-free transit provision if arriving at T2 (once airside you can walk between the terminals)
